# Hierarchy Grids, how the change function in the detailed(sub) grid update a column on the main table

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-grid, kendo-grid

I have a total score field in the master table that I need to update from the detail(sub) table.

I think this would be achieved in the detailed(sub) table, every change I calculate the full total score and need to update the row that the sub table belongs to. I tried the set command on the top object , but it hasn't worked for me yet.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Thanks

-Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call `element` an HTML element in the detail grid. Then finding the `dataItem` corresponding to the parent `grid` that include this element would be:

```
var parentRow = $(elem).closest(".k-detail-row").prev();
//find parent grid
var grid = parentRow.closest("[data-role='grid']").data("kendoGrid");
//get the parent grid row DataItem
var parentDataItem = grid.dataItem(parentRow);
```

In the example http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qxZtk/1/ open the details for one of the rows and click on `Change` button. You will notice that "First Name" is updated.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! (I had the field non editable, another issue hehe)